# hourglass example for java beginners

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner and only learned about the scanner class, JOptionPane, loops, and if statements.

I have to create a java program that prints an hour glass shape based on the number the user inputs. The user will also give a character symbol which is what the hourglass shape will consist of. For example if the user enters "4" for shape and "7" for character then it will look this:

8 number "7" on first now. 6 number "7" on second row. 4 number "7" on third row. 2 number "7" on fourth row. 4 number "7" on fifth row. 6 number "7" on seventh row. 8 number "7" on eight row.

Below is a visual representation of this.

```
77777777
777777
7777
77
7777
777777
77777777
```

The only instructions I was given was:

To read a character use the following code where scanner is Scanner object:

```
char symbol = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point in the general direction of what code to use.

Comment: Well, I would suggest starting with `public class HW1 { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Hello, world!"); } }` and then add functionality from there, one piece at a time, making sure that your code is always in a runnable state.

Comment: Hello J.Doe. Welcome to StackOverflow. This question requests help, but does not yet show what effort you have put in to solve the problem. Please try reducing the problem to the specific issues you are having (reading user input, loops, string formatting), then searching to see if these topics are already addressed in other questions which are already answered. If you're still having trouble after that, feel free to ask questions. Just be sure they comply with StackOverflow's recommended structure, defined here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using your specification and relating the comments to your example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hourglass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // construct scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // get the values for the character and the size of the hourglass from the user
        System.out.print("Enter a symbol: ");
        char symbol = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Enter the size: ");
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        // call method to output the hourglass with the user's input
        hourGlass(symbol, size);                
    }

    static void hourGlass(char symbol, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // loops size times to get the first half + the middle
        {
            // needs to loop 8,6,4,and 2 times; decreases by 2, hence the 2* and -i from outer loop; 
            // I used 0 for the outer loop so 2*(size - 0) = 2 * size to start the top line;
            for (int j = 1; j <= 2 * (size - i); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(symbol);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) // loops 1 less than size times to get the bottom
        {
            // loop for 4,6,and 8 times; increases by 2 so 2 * i will control this; starts at size so size + (2 * i) = size + (2 * 0) = size
            for (int j = 1; j <= size + (2 * i); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(symbol);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```